# Show the total of rows and columns in jquery full calendar based on the month

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I have a Jquery Full calendar. Values to be displayed inside the full calendar is fetched from json. Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/binoymat/T37Hx/9/)

Full calendar HTML Code

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
<div id='cols'></div>
```

Jquery Code

```
var baseEvent;

var $calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
editable: true,
selectable: true,
selectHelper: true,
defaultView: 'month',
events: [
    {"title":"500","start":"Oct 1 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Oct 2 2015"},
    {"title":"500","start":"Oct 3 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Oct 4 2015"},
    {"title":"500","start":"Oct 6 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Oct 7 2015"},
    {"title":"500","start":"Oct 8 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Oct 9 2015"},
    {"title":"500","start":"Oct 10 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Oct 11 2015"},
    {"title":"500","start":"Oct 12 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Oct 13 2015"},
    {"title":"500","start":"Oct 14 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Oct 15 2015"},
    {"title":"500","start":"Oct 16 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Oct 17 2015"},
    {"title":"500","start":"Nov 1 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 2 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 3 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 4 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 5 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 6 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 7 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 8 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 9 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 10 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 11 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 12 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 13 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 14 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 15 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 16 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 17 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 18 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 19 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 20 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 21 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 22 2015"},
    {"title":"100","start":"Nov 23 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Nov 24 2015"},

    {"title":"500","start":"Dec 1 2015"},   
    {"title":"50","start":"Dec 2 2015"}

    ]
 });

var counts = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

baseEvent = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents')
baseEvent.forEach(function(event) {
counts[event.start.getDay()] += parseInt(event.title);
});



counts.forEach(function(count) {
$('#cols').append(' <label>'+count+'</label> ')
});
```

The problem I am facing is that this calculates the entire values of months in that particular column. I am trying to achieve a solution for showing total values rows and columns only in the month that is displayed.

> for eg:- Default loaded month is November.. I want to show values of columns and rows of only for the month of November. When i click to the previous month(October) then only October values for rows and columns has to be displayed. How to achieve this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

- When the calendar renders (which happens at init and on view
  changes), set row and col counters to 0 and search the first row for
  grayed dates. This is your offset to add to each event's date when
  you start totaling rows/cols.
- Check each event as it renders. If it is in the current month, proceed.
- Get the date of the event, increment by the offset, and add it's value to both the row and column arrays.
- After the last event renders, update the dom objects.

(Note, this is for fullcalendar v1. v2 uses Moment instead of Date objects.)

[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scottysmalls/6jhkLh9x/)

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
<div id='cols'>
    <label>0</label>
    <label>0</label>
    <label>0</label>
    <label>0</label>
    <label>0</label>
    <label>0</label>
    <label>0</label>
</div>
<div id='rows'>
    <label>0</label>
    <label>0</label>
    <label>0</label>
    <label>0</label>
    <label>0</label>
    <label>0</label>
    <label>0</label>
</div>      

var $calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ...
    eventRender: eventRenderCallback,
    viewRender: viewRenderCallback,
    eventAfterAllRenderCallback: eventAfterAllRenderCallback,
    ...
});

var rowTotals = [];
var columnTotals = [];
var offset = 0;

function eventRenderCallback(event,element){
    var viewDateMonth = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate').getMonth();
    if(event.start.getMonth() == viewDateMonth){
        addToDateArray(event.start.getDate(), parseInt(event.title));
    }
}

function eventAfterAllRenderCallback(view){
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        var label = $("#rows label:nth-child(" + (i+1) + ")");
        label.html(rowTotals[i]);     
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        var label = $("#cols label:nth-child(" + (i+1) + ")");
        label.html(columnTotals[i]);     
    }
}

function viewRenderCallback(view,element){
    offset = $("tr.fc-week.fc-first td.fc-other-month").length;
    rowTotals = [0,0,0,0,0,0];
    columnTotals = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

    if(view.name == "agendaDay"){
        $("#rows label").show();
        $("#cols label").hide();
        $("#cols label:nth-child(" + (view.start.getDay()+1) + ")").show();
    }else if(view.name == "agendaWeek"){
        $("#cols label").show();
        $("#rows label").hide();
        var row = Math.floor((view.start.getDate() + offset - 1) / 7);
        $("#rows label:nth-child(" + (row+1) + ")").show();
    }else {
        $("#cols label").show();
        $("#rows label").show();
    }
}                   

function addToDateArray(date,num){
    var pos = date + offset;
    var row = Math.floor((pos - 1) / 7);
    var col = (pos - 1) % 7

    rowTotals[row] += num;
    columnTotals[col] += num;
}
```

Comment: I just checked the fiddle, it still shows all the values for the month of OCT, NOV, DEC..  how do we add a property to the event in fullcalendar?? Is there  a bulit-in method in full calendar?? Would it possible to edit it in the fiddle??

Comment: I updated my answer with a different approach. It works for the day view as well, hiding the rest of the counters. Note: I had to use the next stable version of fullcalendar (1.6.3) as the version you had in your original fiddle (1.6.1) has a bug where viewRender does not function correctly (see http://bit.ly/1MT96Ey and http://bit.ly/1PQfges )

Comment: hi scottysmalls, works well... just one question... i tried getting the  rows using event.getWeek(); I wasn't getting any rows value.. i need 4 row for each week with the total of the values below it..

Comment: i tried using it this way http://jsfiddle.net/binoymat/6jhkLh9x/3/ values are taken inside the full calendar

Comment: problems with that fiddle: getDate is a fullcalendar method, getWeek isnt: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/getDate/ . Also, you can't have two eventRenderCallback functions. Just add the row code to the existing eventRender callback.

Comment: scottysmalls, I am totally confused... don't understand the flow here... would u pls update the fiddle for rows too??? that would be of great help!!!

Comment: Sure, I will design it, but the values shown is wrong.. I mean row values what is shown is 850 550 500 300, it is suppose to be 950, 500, 550,200

Comment: You are right - It didn't occur to me that where the 1st of the month is placed changes based on an internal fullcalendar algorithm. I'm not sure, i'll have to think about it. It may involve looking through the dom with jquery. I'm going to revert the fiddle because, well, it's not right.

Comment: alrite scottysmalls... but that was a great attempt.. I thought this problem was solved.. except for rows, guess columns are fine which displays value based on the month.. which was cool... If u find a solution, pls update here!!

Comment: This is brilliant!!!! AMAZING!!! hey, just one last and final piece of code here... just to get the total of the rows.. I mean, 950 500 550 200 (2200), this (2200) has to come at the end. Just this one missing piece too pls

Comment: also, i tried removing the json and applied a json link, pls see what happens in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/binoymat/6jhkLh9x/9/

Comment: Onload of the page, it shows 0 values, only when we move to the next or previous month, values r displayed

Comment: hey, I was able to fix the onload part of json

Comment: so just the total for rows remains now

Comment: scottysmalls, AMAZING!!! ALL WHAT I EXPECTED!! I am applying your answer so that this would be helpful for other users as well!!!

Comment: i have used  weekNumbers: true we have total row values and column values like this 950 500 550 200 (2200), 700 300 300 200 250 200 250... Gets a little confusing when a new user looks at these row & col values... So i was trying to bring the weeknumber next to the row value and Days next the column values.. here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/binoymat/6jhkLh9x/11/ how can i add Week number next to the row values??? something like this.. (W 44)950, (W 45)500, (W 46)550, (W 47)200 (2200) and for column values something like this (Sun)700 (Mon)300 (Tue)300 (Wed)200 (Thu)250 (Fri)200 (Sat)250?

Comment: And, Is there any print options available in Fullcalendar??? If so, how do we add them in the fullcalendar???

Comment: I'd suggest creating a new question for the week numbers. It's good stack overflow practice not to keep adding onto one question once it's been answered (this one actually got a bit long.) As for the printing, i would suggest the same except there are already quite a few questions with answers for that already. Just search 'fullcalendar printing' and you'll see them.

Comment: hi scott, I have create a new question for this called "Jquery Full calendar, display Week Numbers and Days into the output", pls find this question for a solution!!! thanks once again!!